# Css print - page break on content

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a web page which prints its content on a pre-printed receipt template. The problem I am facing is that the template has three sections on each page. 
Header section with bill no, customer name etc..
Content section which is populated in tabular row format. This section is dynamic and cannot predict the number of rows and height.
Footer section contains sum of amount etc..

I would like to keep the header only in first page, footer only in the bottom part of last page. The dynamic middle part should break and distribute in multiple pages depends on the content. Header and footer part of intermediate pages should remain empty on its respective space.

Could anyone please help me to make this structure with html5 and css3.

Answer (score 0):

### Hello there this is my solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
// does not show the div other than print
@media all {
  .page-break   { display: none; }
}
//make it break the page
@media print {
  .page-break   { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
  #content{
    color:blue;
  }
}
</style>
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<section id="content">
  <h1>CONTENT</h1>
</section>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<footer>
  <h1>FOTTER</h1>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps, for more info here is a **[link](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)**